# How much can $\Delta_0$-definable set functions increase rank?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I've seen conflicting remarks on "growth rate" of functions $V\rightarrow V$ that are $\Delta_0$-definable in $V$:

- In Keith J. Devlin's ["An introduction to the fine structure of the constructible hierarchy"](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30905237.pdf), lemma 2 says that $\Delta_0$-definable functions $V\rightarrow V$ are rudimentary, and it's remarked on p.8 that "though [rudimentary] functions increase rank they only do so by a finite amount."
- However, p.968 of Rathjen's paper ["A Proof-Theoretic Characterization of the Primitive Recursive Set Functions"](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/PrimRec.pdf#page=16) claims $g:V\rightarrow V$ is $\Delta_0$-definable in $V$, where $g(x)$ is the smallest standard model of KP containing $x$. But $g(x)$'s rank may be transfinitely higher than $x$'s rank (e.g. when $x=\omega\cdot 2$), which appears to contradict the first claim?

If I had to guess where my misunderstanding is, it's probably about Devlin's remark, since on page 9 of Devlin's paper it's also claimed that $\Delta_0$-definable functions $V\rightarrow V$ can increase rank by a transfinite amount [despite being rudimentary].

---

**Edit**: For anyone coming to this question wondering not about the discrepancy between rud and $\Delta_0$-definable functions, but instead about actual known bounds on how fast $\Delta_0$-definable set functions can grow, here are two (although I'm not sure how tight either is):

- A lower bound is given by Rathjen's remark that $x\mapsto\textrm{smallest recursively Mahlo set }\supset x$ is $\Delta_0$-definable, also on p.968 of "[A Proof-Theoretic Characterization of the Primitive Recursive Set Functions](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/PrimRec.pdf#page=16)".
- An upper bound comes from Theorem 36 of Levy's *A hierarchy of formulas in set theory*, which it follows that $\Sigma_1$-definable $f:V\rightarrow V$ has the bound $\forall x(\textrm{hcard}(f(x))<x^{+L})$, where $\bullet^{+L}$ is cardinal successor within $L$. I believe if $V=L$, we may be able to improve this to $\forall x(f(x)\in L_{\textrm{min}\{\sigma >\textrm{L-rank}(x)\mid\sigma\textrm{ is stable}\}})$ by noting that the predicate $``\exists y.y=f(x)"$ is $\Sigma_1$ with parameter $x$, so if we have some stable ordinal $\sigma$ such that $x\in L_\sigma$, then $L_\sigma\vDash``\exists y.y=f(x)"$, i.e. $f(x)\in L_\sigma$.

Comment: Lemma 2 says that $\Delta_0$-definable relations are rudimentary, not that $\Delta_0$ functions are rudimentary. (And it doesn't say "despite being rudimentary")

Comment: There's a paragraph resolving this tension in Devlin's book, in the fine structure chapter, immediately preceding lemma 1.2.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look in that chapter, and also edit the question to show that "despite being rudimentary" were my own words.

Comment: I think the issue is the difference in what "rudimentary" means for relations vs. functions.  Rudimentary relations are of the form $R=\{x:f(x)\neq \emptyset\}$ for some rudimentary function $f$ which allows for more complexity than being built up by some standard functions.  The results say $\Delta_0$-relations $=$ rud relations, and rud functions $\subsetneq$ $\Delta_0$-relations.  So rudimentary functions are rudimentary relations, but not all rudimentary relations that happen to be functions are rudimentary *as* functions.